# Set imeOptions for whole app

Tags: android

Is it possible to set `imeOptions` for the whole app globally to `actionDone` instead of specifying it on each editText?
Or is the only possibility to add the options to each editText individually?

Comment: create custom edittext with imeoptions and use your custom edittext in whole app

Comment: Nothing Possible in the world :)

Comment: @Lingeshwaran thanks. I think that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you apply style in all edittext then only change style in like

```
    <style name="editText">
<item name="android:imeOptions">actionDone</item>
</style>
```

other wise you can apply all edittext box in individually for imeOptions.